# Form navigation showing unsorted records in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form in MS Access that have 153 records. The "ID Number" field is primary key and its format is auto numbers.

When I navigate this form to "First Record" it showing "ID Number" **68** instead of **"1"**.
On "next record" it showing "ID Number" **97** instead of **"2"**. On next record it showing "ID Number" **75** instead of **"3"** and so on.

I have not use any custom macro to navigate records. But I don't know why my form showing unsorted records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than relying on the order in which the records appear in a table/query being the order in which they are presented by a form, it is more reliable to specify a sort order either as part of the SQL for the Record Source, or within the **Order By** property found within the Form Data properties, with **Order By On Load** set to **Yes**.

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been resolved by doing the following steps

- Open the form in design view
- In property sheet removed the Record Source
- Save and close the form
- Open the form again in Design view
- Re-enter the Record Source.

Comment: That is pure luck only. Do implement the method described by Lee.